# Prononciations des terminaisons du futur et du conditionnel

Tags: prononciation, linguistique, conditionnel, futur-simple

Quelle est la différence de prononciation à la fin des verbes dans le futur et le conditionnel?

**Par exemple:**

- Je serai
- Je serais

---

Je pense qu'un a le 'e' ouvert et l'autre a le 'e' fermé, mais je ne sais pas comment prononcer la différence.

If you could also provide a geographical context for the pronunciations, that would be ideal.  Thank you.

**Peut-être que quelqu'un peut me donner un exemple d'un mot français ou même d'un mot anglais qui contient ces sons.**